# onAppear and onDisappear wont be called when it's the last window

Tags: swiftui

MRE

```
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
    }       
}
```

and then

```
struct ContentView: View {   
    var body: some View {
        Text("hi")
           .onAppear()   // not called
           .onDisappear()  //not called
 }
}
```

Run the app

1. appear is called
2. close the window, **disappear not called**
3. home screen launch the app again, window is shown, **appear not called**

Is this a bug? And if so how to get around?

Comment: iOS or macOS? You mention "close the window" which sounds like this is on macOS, but also "home screen", which doesn't exist in macOS.

Comment: If you're looking to perform actions in connection with the app lifecycle then try searching on `ScenePhase`.

Comment: @Sweeper visionOS

Comment: @BenzyNeez no I'm looking to have actions in connection to the window lifecycle

Comment: think of disappear like when it is removed from within a window